# ESP8266 - server.write() doesn't work

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi

I have a few Arduinos with ESPs, one of which is set up to measure temperature, and I'd like to have it send commands to other connected Arduinos to perform various functions (open/close valves, etc.)

In other words, the only communication I need is for one server to hopefully broadcast to a few clients. I don't really need to discern which client is which.

I am struggling to make sense of some of the documentation, and this is new to me.

For starters, I'm just trying to get any communication at all functional before I do the next parts.

My server device is set up as a soft access point and a WiFiServer.

My server ESP code looks something like this:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

const byte ON = 2;
const byte OFF = 1;
int message;
    
WiFiServer server(80);
    
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  WiFi.softAP("access", "point");
  server.begin();
}
    
void loop()
{
  server.write(ON);
  delay(1000);
  server.write(OFF);
  delay(1000);
}
```

My client code looks something like this:

```cpp
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
    
const byte ON = 2;
const byte OFF = 1;
byte ip[] = {192, 168, 4, 1};
WiFiClient client;
int message;
    
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  // connect to wifi.
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  WiFi.begin("access", "point");
    
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
  }
    
  // Now connect to server object
  if (client.connect(ip, 80) == 1) {
    Serial.println("Connected");
  } else {
    Serial.println("Not Connected");
  }
  delay(10000);
}   
    
void loop() {
  if (client.connected()) {
    Serial.println("Waiting for Data");
    while(!client.available()) {}
    String message = client.read();
    Serial.println(message);
  }
}
```

The client code does connect to the server, and gets stuck at the "Waiting for Data" line, never getting out of the `while (!client.available)` loop, so it clearly isn't receiving anything.

I'm sure I must look super dumb here, can someone help me understand the proper way to do what I want to do? Stuff I have seen online is primarily client -> server communication. Do I HAVE to ping the server with something in order to receive something back?

Answer (score 1):

In esp8266 Arduino before version 3, `write` [was not implemented](https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/2.7.2/esp8266wifi/server-class.html#write-write-to-all-clients-not-supported) in WiFiServer.

In version 3 WiFiServer doesn't have `write`, but class ArduinoWiFiServer implements the print-to-all-clients functionality.

Documentation link: https://arduino-esp8266.readthedocs.io/en/3.1.2/esp8266wifi/server-class.html

I am the author of `ArduinoWiFiServer` class.